# LocalDateTime for IST(Indian Standard Time) with ZoneOffset in cleaner way

Tags: java, java-time

```
private static int gmtOffet = 19800;

public long convertToLong(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(gmtOffet)).toEpochMilli();
}
```

Here I have calculated zone offset offset explicitly which is 5h30m for India. Then converted to seconds and used to get local time in miliseconds.
Is there a better way to do this where I don't have to calculate the time offset but some enum etc picks the offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need milliseconds since the epoch, it’s most practical to get them from an `Instant` as you do.

Regarding the offset it’s cleaner and better to get it from the library:

```
private static final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");

public long convertToLong(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return localDateTime.atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

This conveys why you are using the offset that you are. It is also proof for historic dates (India has not always used offset +05:30) and future dates in case Indian politicians decide on a different offset some time in the future.

You may ask yourself once more whether you really need that millisecond value? It’s low-level. It’s better to represent a moment in time as an `Instant` object or other date and time object. Of course, if it’s for a legacy API outside your control, you have no choice.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Instant is not appropriate in the first place, really. Seconds (as in, just the seconds bit of a clock, with the minutes and such removed) is a human time concept. `Instant` is for computer time, and `LocalDate`, `ZonedDateTime` etc are for humans with their crazy shenanigans with time zones and leap years and leap seconds and russian revolutions and calendars and completely astronomically irrelevant and unfounded concepts such as weeks. Humans be crazy!

```
ZoneId INDIA_ZONE = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
ZonedDateTime zdt = yourLDT.atZone(INDIA_ZONE);
int seconds = zdt.getSecond();
```

etcetera.